# Magento 1.7.0.2 customer password reset doens't work

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-account, supee-6788, password-recovery

I have a problem which has kept me occupied for three days already.
When doing a password reset, customers get the email, and the token generation is valid, but when they click the link then they will be taken to a page which has the header, left column and footer and a blank col-main.

This is the wrong layout, it should get 1 column only...

I've done SUPEE 6788 and I've made sure that:

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
<label>Reset a Password</label>
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>

<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Was updated to:

```
<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
<label>Reset a Password</label>
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>

<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Other customer account layout in the customer.xml
Customer account ForgotPassword block:

```
<customer_account_forgotpassword translate="label">
    <label>Customer Forgot Password Form</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Forgot Your Password</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer"><title>Password forgotten</title></action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <!--<block type="core/template" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml"/>-->
        <block type="customer/account_forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="customer/form/forgotpassword.phtml" />
    </reference>
</customer_account_forgotpassword>
```

Customer account Change Forgotten Block:

```
<customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_changeforgotten>
```

Customer account Reset Password block:

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
<label>Reset a Password</label>
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>

<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
</reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>
```

However, this is not the problem, I see the problem is the biggest in the fact that it goes to 2 col left layout while in customer.xml I clearly have the 1 column page.

I've spent three days now, and I do not know what to google for anymore :) Also here offcourse I couldn't find this case.

Adding also controller code:

```
public function changeForgottenAction()
{
    try {
        list($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken) = $this->_getRestorePasswordParameters($this->_getSession());
        $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
        $this->_redirect('*/*/forgotpassword');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add two line in xml

```
<remove name="right"/>
<remove name="left"/>
```

before your code

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
    </action>
    <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
        <title>Reset a Password</title>
    </action>
</reference>
<reference name="content">
    <block type="customer/account_changeforgotten" name="changeForgottenPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

Comment: It is there, StackExcahnge has for some reason cut the first part off... <customer_account_changeforgotten translate="label">
        <label>Reset a Password</label>
        <remove name="right"/>
        <remove name="left"/>   ... Fixed it in my starting question, sorry :)

Comment: Can you please tell me the redirect link from email

Comment: https://www.stalapotheek.nl/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=1845&token=5098c1d76f62c50803156beb785d663c

Comment: Please add resetpassword and changeforgotten function code to your question

Comment: Added today Prashant, and thanks for thinking with me on this one.

Comment: Right now your link is working. and i am asking for your controller action of  customer/controllers/AccountController  in function changeforgotten(). add code of that function in your answer

Comment: Hi Prashant, right now the link is expired, so that one gives the proper 'Link expired notice: insert email address' actually, the new token request link also doesn't work: https://www.stalapotheek.nl/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=1845&token=bd00c6d4c0c6a56868fbca5ddad19d18

Comment: controller code added to topic start question, new token link: https://www.stalapotheek.nl/customer/account/resetpassword/?id=1845&token=d04a153b61b2bcd49db9b5ed8784bd6b